# UIWebView showing black screen while lock the iPad device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

Our app is based on the `UIWebView`. I have got fully black screen When i locked the iPad device while the PDF document is loading in the `UIWebview`. Please let me know that how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

in your

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

you need to add some code to either reload the PDF if it's currently showing the PDF, or pause the loading.